# Proof: Lemma 5.6.2 - Elements of Real Analysis (C.G. Denlinger)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

I reading the book "Elements of Real Analysis, C.G.Denlinger".. and I need the proof of Lemma 5.6.2:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since we are talking about fundamentals here: How is this $x$ given; in other words: What is your model of ${\mathbb R}$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter, $\Bbb{R}$ is ordered field..

Comment: @Soviet: I think you should write "$\mathbb{R}$ is a complete ordered field". $\mathbb{Q}$ is also an ordered field and this completeness is the the only property which distinguishes reals from rationals.

Comment: @Paramanad, I'm sorry.. of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the intervals $$I_n=[x-2^{-n},x-2^{-n-1}]$$

and pick a rational in each of them.

Comment: Can I use $\frac{\lfloor x \cdot 10^n \rfloor}{10^n}$ ?

Comment: Well, yes. You have to prove it is increasing, though.

Comment: I proofed $\frac{\lfloor x \cdot 10^n \rfloor}{10^n} \leq \frac{\lfloor x \cdot 10^{n+1} \rfloor }{10^{n+1}}$ by induction and it is true.. therefore is it increasing?

Comment: @Soviet Correct.

Comment: thanks soo much!